# How to toggle the field value from true to false and vice versa in ASP.NET Core 6

Tags: c#, mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm building an API using ASP.NET Core 6 with mongodb as database. I'm trying to set a certain field to toggle from true to false and vice versa. If the field `isactive:"True"` then I have to update it to false and vice versa.

I have figured out how to update the value, but I have to **toggle this field to opposite value automatically** without having to specify the value.

Here is the repository class:

```cs
public bool UpdateStatus(string id)
{
    _activity.UpdateOne(x => x.Id == id,
                Builders<Activity>.Update.Set(u => u.IsActive,false));
    return true;
}
```

Controller for above repository:

```cs
public ActionResult putbystatus(string id)
{
    var existingactivity = activityRepository.Get(id);
    if (existingactivity == null)
    {
        return NotFound($"Activity with provider id = {id} not found");
    }
    activityRepository.UpdateStatus(id);
    return NoContent();
}
```

Comment: I don't know your language's syntax/grammar, but to toggle the value you just need to logically `not` the current value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can write like below

```
public bool UpdateStatus(string id)
{
   var filter =  Builders<Activity>.Filter.Eq("Id", id);
    _activity.UpdateOne(filter,
                Builders<Activity>.Update.Set(u => u.IsActive,!_activity.Find(filter).FirstOrDefault().IsActive));
    return true;
}



//or if you can modify the repository to accept IsActive value


public bool UpdateStatus(string id, bool isActive)
{
    _activity.UpdateOne(x => x.Id == id,
                Builders<Activity>.Update.Set(u => u.IsActive, isActive));
    return true;
}

//Controller for above repository

public ActionResult putbystatus(string id)
        {
            var existingactivity = activityRepository.Get(id);
            if (existingactivity == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Activity with provider id = {id} not found");
            }
            activityRepository.UpdateStatus(id,!existingactivity.IsActive);
            return NoContent();
        }


[enter image description here][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/tytAK.png
```

Comment: Doesn't work, this one makes me to update all the fields instead  of toggling that one field IsActive

Comment: @Muralidharan It will update the one field only as we are passing u.IsActive to update.set method. can you explain why it will not work? It worked for me.