# How to update the boolean field from true to false and vice versa

Tags: mongodb, asp.net-core-webapi, asp.net-core-6.0

I'm building an API using ASP.NET Core 6 with mongodb as database. I'm trying to set a certain field to toggle from true to false and vice versa. If the field `isactive:"True"` then I have to update it to false and vice versa.

I have figured it out to update the value but I have to toggle this field to opposite value automatically without having to specify the value.

Here is the repository class:

```
public bool UpdateStatus(string id)
{
    _activity.UpdateOne(x => x.Id == id,
                Builders<Activity>.Update.Set(u => u.IsActive,false));
    return true;
}
```

Controller for above repository

```
public ActionResult putbystatus(string id)
        {
            var existingactivity = activityRepository.Get(id);
            if (existingactivity == null)
            {
                return NotFound($"Activity with provider id = {id} not found");
            }
            activityRepository.UpdateStatus(id);
            return NoContent();
        }
```

Comment: Sound like same question as [How to toggle the field value from true to false and vice versa in ASP.NET Core 6](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73583920/how-to-toggle-the-field-value-from-true-to-false-and-vice-versa-in-asp-net-core)

Answer (score 1):

negate it like this:

boolean_variable = !boolean_variable